# Recommended Practices - API Authentication for new user creation

Tags: web-services, security, https

All calls on our site are over https and almost all resource calls require a unique user specific token which is returned to the client on login. However, certain calls like forgot password or initial user creation require a different authentication mechanism. A super-user token comes to mind, but I don;t see how it can be securely handed to the client (hardcoding it does not seem to be an option). What are the recommended practices for authenticating these types of calls please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionality like creating a new account or resetting a forgotten password are typically not secured at all (other than transport security - https) since they must be done by definition without the user being logged on.

What is the threat you are worried about? If it is that someone tries to create a gazillion accounts, you could build rules in your account creation logic that a given IP-address can also create a limited number of accounts in a certain time period.

If you're worried that someone may use the reset password functionality to brute force password, you can limit the number of password resets a user can attempt on a certain account.